# Searching for Embedded C library to operate on Big numbers which do not use standard libc?

Tags: embedded, static-libraries, gmp, bignum

I have to operate on Very large numbers may be 2048 bytes for implementation of RSA. As per the rules of Automotive domain i cant use bignum library which uses standard libc. I have searched for GMP and Polarssl but they all uses malloc() and other things.

So is there any library/method available that do not rely on libc and also manages such big numbers..? ???

Comment: I'm not sure whether this meets your requirement, but checkout the [BigDigits](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) library.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what is not acceptable in `libc`.  You can alter the source to not use an allocator, if that is your problem.  I think it would be better to concentrate on the issue, than to ask for a recommendation.  Ie, the **method** part of your question is promising.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find any decent big integer C library, that not use `malloc`, `calloc` and possibly `realloc` or whatever dynamic allocation, because the whole point of **arbitrary** precision numbers is to go beyond limited, platform-dependent stack size and for second it's much more flexible method than compile-time static memory allocation.

My guess is to adapt `mini-gmp` package to overcome your specific limitations. (you will find it under main directory along with some tests). It contains one header file and C-source file, so it should be a lot simpler to "cut-off" `libc` dependency rather than fully-featured release, however it will be not that fast as GMP relies heavily on highly-optimized assembly code for various CPU architectues.

As suggested by *kkrambo* you may also try [`BigDigits`](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) library with `NO_ALLOCS` option, that is available since version 2.2:

> Added the NO_ALLOCS option to compile the "mp" library without using
>   any memory allocation.

Comment: The [BigDigits](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) library includes a core library for which memory allocations can be disabled with the `NO_ALLOCS` preprocessor definition.  The core library will then use fixed arrays and you can adjust the size of these arrays based on knowledge of your application.

Comment: @kkrambo: I didn't notice that, answer is edited, thanks for enlightening :-)